# USB sound card regognized as stereo instead Digital SPDIF passtrhough

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, spdif

I bought a USB sound card which is based on [CM6206 chip](http://www.cmedia.com.tw/ProductsDetail/page-p/C1Serno-25/C2Serno-26/C3Serno-0/PSerno-23.html). And it shows as CM106 like device on Ubuntu volume control.
There's a optical out that works well with Windows, after installing drivers.

However on Ubuntu, the device recognized as a stereo SPDIF device. Which is incorrect. I need this to be recognize as a SPDIF device, that I can pass-through DD, DTS non-PCM sound to receiver.

Anybody know how to get this work?
Or by adding some hacks to alsa driver?

Answer (score 0):

The CM6206 uses a non-standard method of labelling non-audio S/PDIF data. It's described in the datasheet, but not yet implemented in the driver.

Comment: Is there any work around available for this issue?